# What are the main differences between the "I, Robot: movie and Asimov's "Little Lost Robot" story

Tags: adaptation-comparison, isaac-asimov, i-robot-2004, i-robot, little-lost-robot

From wikipedia [I, Robot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_robot#2004_film) entry:

> The film I, Robot, starring Will Smith, was released by Twentieth Century Fox on July 16, 2004 in the United States. Its plot incorporates elements of "Little Lost Robot,"[7] some of Asimov's character names and the Three Laws. However, the plot of the movie is mostly original work adapted from a screenplay Hardwired by Jeff Vintar completely unlinked to Asimov's stories[7]

What are the main similarities/ differences in the movie *I, Robot* versus Asimov's story [*Little Lost Robot*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055338256X)?

Comment: From what I recall, Little Lost Robot doesn't contain cringe-inducing product placement.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without getting snarky. Other than character names, the very general concept of identifying one particular robot out of a group of identical mass-produced ones, and the three laws, the movie is completely unrelated to any of Isaac Asimov's writings. I think he would have liked the old-style robots, though.

Comment: it seems many that assert there is little connection may not be all that familiar with asimov's writing. asimov wrote a _lot_ of stories about robots (maybe thousands of pages) & also wonder if there are parallels/ plot elements across multiple stories (2020 hindsight probably should have adjd the question a bit to reflect that). are there any stories where a robot is a suspect in a crime? pursued/ questioned by the police? malfunctioning robots not correctly following 3 laws of robotics? etc? found some further [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Robot_(film)#Similarities_with_the_book)

Comment: @JoeL - so for some reason stamping a serial number on the robot has somehow gone out of style.  That's how companies do the identification now for cars, computers...

Comment: @vzn - There are a few Asimov stories where a robot is a suspect in a crime. Most notably the Elijah Baley mysteries. But none of them bare any resemblance to the Will Smith movie. For one thing, Asimov's robot stories were mostly mysteries and had little if any action sequences.

Comment: @Oldcat From the source: “But we had to have ro­bots of a dif­fer­ent na­ture. So just a few of the NS-2 model, the Nestors, that is, were pre­pared with a mod­i­fied First Law. To keep it quiet, all NS-2’s are man­u­fac­tured with­out se­r­ial num­bers; mod­i­fied mem­bers are de­liv­ered here along with a group of nor­mal ro­bots; and, of course, all our kind are under the strictest im­pres­sion­ment never to tell of their mod­i­fi­ca­tion to unau­tho­rized per­son­nel.” He wore an em­bar­rassed smile, “This has all worked out against us now.”

Comment: I guess Asimov knew of that plot hole, but it is a poor fix. Nobody would know or care if modified NS-2s were made with a Serial # starting with a key code different than the unmodified others, such as MAD_ROBOT_DANGER_023455.

Comment: @Oldcat It is a bit forced, isn't it? But the good doctor was very fond of the classic "locked room" style mystery story, and wasn't above using a hammer to fit a story into that framework. Even the great ones got lazy sometimes.

Comment: @joe think the serial number concept is worthy of expanding into an answer, am not able to follow all the brief comments on story vs movie vs plot glitch etc (ymmv). acc to the replies apparently the movie is what is known in hollywood as ["high concept"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-concept) but also it seems the concepts were quite original & unique to asimov.

Comment: @vzn For me, my main gripe about the movie was the "Frankenstein" theme. For the most part, Asimov deliberately stayed away from that trope. The conflicts in his robot stories had more to do with the basic difference between human thinking and machine logic, intuition vs. programming. "I, Robot" isn't a bad movie in it's own right, but it misses the main point that Asimov tried to make - the only thing to fear from technology, even sentient technology, is the way we use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only connection between the story "Little Lost Robot" and the movie *I, Robot* is that the missing robot was in both cases able to elude capture and otherwise act against the wishes of the humans surrounding it because it was not operating under the complete Three Laws of Robotics.  In "Little Lost Robot" the missing robot operated under a modified First Law: it could through inaction allow human beings to come to harm.  In *I, Robot*, the (briefly) missing robot Sonny had a secondary brain that didn't seem to be operating under the influence of the Laws at all.

Comment: Not quite true. Many character names are borrowed from the short-story by the film, including the name of the robot series in question; NS-5, instead of the short-story's NS-10.

Comment: It's true that there's borrowing, but it's an very different story. Like many robot stories it's based on the 3 laws, that's almost the only similarity.